Projective Geometry and Curvature of Surfaces
I'm currently exploring projective geometry and came across an old French book titled Introduction à la Géométrie Projective Différentielle des Surfaces. At one point, the authors derive the definitions of maximum and minimum curvatures (you can refer to the images attached for details). After establishing these concepts, the text then mentions that the same ideas will be generalized to projective geometry. However, instead of using circles and spheres as in Euclidean geometry, the authors indicate that osculating quadrics will be used for this purpose.
What I find unclear is how the use of quadrics actually constitutes a generalization of curvature in projective geometry. While I understand that osculating spheres are typically used to define curvature via second-order contact in Euclidean settings, it’s not immediately obvious how replacing them with quadrics achieves a meaningful generalization under projective transformations.
Additionally, the text derives curvature by discussing spheres that have second-order contact with the surface. However, I’m having trouble believing that a projective transformation would preserve this second-order contact between a surface and a quadric. Can someone explain why this is the case, or provide some clarification on how the generalization works in the projective setting?
The book is available here:https://archive.org/details/introductionlage0000guid/page/52/mode/1up?view=theater



I think @MvG can help.

Not sure I can help. I have too little experience in differential geometry (which sounds like a useful tag to add). And I don't fully understand that book's notation: what does the $+(3)$ in equation (1) signify? It doesn't seem to be the number three, because otherwise the origin wouldn't be included as the text claims. You might get more help by translating the French to English, and by extending the quote a bit further: the authors seem to characterize their quadric by a triple point of intersection and two asymptotes, if I read the subsequent text right. That feels relevant.
